# Role of ASCII character variables in Data.Word8

Tags: haskell

I was trying to find a variable for the ord value of a letter (a=97,A=65) to make my code easier to read. I found that the `Data.Word8` module defines some variables for characters in the following way:

```
_a = 0x61
_b = 0x62
_c = 0x63
_d = 0x64
```

etc.

However, when I try to use these variables I get the following error:

```
Found hole `_x' with type: t
Where: `t' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the inferred type of it :: t at <interactive>:27:1
Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:27:1)
In the expression: _x
In an equation for `it': it = _x
```

This is the first time I've encountered typed-holes. After looking at an introduction to typed-holes I still don't understand (a) Why `Data.Word8` uses them and (b) How can the typed-holes appear on the LHS of the equals sign. In the introduction I read they only appear on the RHS (c) How can I use these variables in my code?

If anyone has an explanation it would be appreciated.

Edit: I feel a bit stupid now. I was mixing up the `Data.Word8` package with the `Data.Word` package which contains the `Word8` data type.

Comment: Could not reproduce. After importing `Data.Word8` (did you forget to do this?), the `_x` constant works fine. Perhaps you should include detailed instructions for reproducing your error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> (a) Why Data.Word8 uses them

It doesn't. You forgot to `import Data.Word8`. Therefore, the identifier `_x` is unknown:

```
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> _x

<interactive>:2:1:
    Found hole ‘_x’ with type: t
    Where: ‘t’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the inferred type of it :: t at <interactive>:2:1
    Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:2:1)
    In the expression: _x
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = _x
ghci> import Data.Word8
ghci> _x
120
```

> (b) How can the typed-holes appear on the LHS of the equals sign

It *does* appear on the right hand side, because GHCi uses `it = <last-expression>`. Since the last expression was `_x`, you suddenly have a typed hole.

> (c) How can I use these variables in my code?

***Import*** `Data.Word8`.

Comment: Well, I feel dumb. I think it was an unfortunate coincidence that typed-holes involve similar errors as undefined variables and involve underscores. That was quite a rabbit hole.